# How to check if an object changed its state in next 7 days?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have two R `data.frame` describing state change events of certain objects. `df1` is collection of all `x to y` state transitions and `df2` contains all `y to anything` transitions. I want to exclude all `x to y` transitions of an object if it was followed by any `y to anything` transition within next 7 days. Both `data.frame` can contain multiple entries for an `object_id` and `state_change`. Also, object can change state multiple times in a day. Following is the code to reproduce sample input data.

```
df1 <- data.frame(object_id = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'd'), 
                  state_change = c('x to y', 'x to y', 'x to y', 'x to y'), 
                  event_date = c('2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-01'))

> df1
  object_id state_change event_date
1         a       x to y 2018-01-01
2         b       x to y 2018-01-01
3         a       x to y 2018-01-05
4         d       x to y 2018-01-01

> df2 <- data.frame(object_id = c('b', 'a', 'd'), 
                    state_change = c('y to z', 'y to x', 'y to z'), 
                    event_date = c('2018-01-01', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-15'))

> df2
  object_id state_change event_date
1         b       y to z 2018-01-01
2         a       y to x 2018-01-03
3         d       y to z 2018-01-15
```

I would like to change `df1` to following, because for `object_id = d`, `x to y` transition was not followed by `y to anything` transition within next 7 days:

```
> df1
  object_id state_change event_date
1         d       x to y 2018-01-01
```

I am new to time series analysis in R and this seems like a fundamental question. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some effort, came up with following solution. Not sure if I'm missing out any case.

```
# combine all events, arrange by object_id and event date, mutate next event and next object
> df3 <- rbind(df1, df2) %>% 
      arrange(object_id, event_date) %>% 
      mutate(next_event = lead(event_date),
             next_object = lead(object_id))

# resulting dataframe containing all events
> df3
  object_id state_change event_date next_event next_object
1         a       x to y 2018-01-01 2018-01-05           a
2         a       x to y 2018-01-05 2018-01-03           a
3         a       y to x 2018-01-03 2018-01-01           b
4         b       x to y 2018-01-01 2018-01-01           b
5         b       y to z 2018-01-01 2018-01-01           d
6         d       x to y 2018-01-01 2018-01-15           d
7         d       y to z 2018-01-15       <NA>        <NA>


# remove all x to y changes which are followed by y to anything within next 7 days
> df1_filtered <- df3 %>% 
      filter(as.numeric(difftime(next_event,event_date, units = 'days')) > 7 |
             object_id != next_object | 
             is.na(next_object) | 
             is.na(as.numeric(difftime(next_event, event_date, units = 'days')))) %>% 
      filter(state_change == 'x to y')

# final result
> df1_filtered

  object_id state_change event_date next_event next_object
1         d       x to y 2018-01-01 2018-01-15           d
```